# Wordpress : How can add user block to new post type

Tags: wordpress

i will create new post type in my wordpress called "Food" , and i need to add any new post in this post type to user register in my site.

so when i add new post in my post type "Food" , i need to select this post for which user.

how can make this.

thankx

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Can you try to restate it? Do you want to create a new user with the same same as post type?  Or vice versa?

Comment: @Chris Herbert i need to show all user register in my site with the poste type to add post to this user,same as news, when add news you need to add this news to authers

Comment: do you mean you have a role or added capabilities to a user to manage a custom post type, and you want these users to show in the `authors` meta box in post editor screen?

Comment: @gwillie yes i want these users to show in the authors meta box in post editor screen

Answer (score 0):

you're in luck today as i am currently doing what you are asking :)

wordpress only displays users with a role of `author`. basically you have to remove `authordiv` meta box, add another meta box with the same html as the original `authordiv`, find users with correct role/capability and build a select, so the code below is my implementation, you'll need to modify it to suit your needs:

```
// add authordiv if user is admin or is allowed to change author of post !important
global $current_user;
if(in_array(array('administrator','change_post_author'), $current_user->allcaps))
  add_meta_box('authordiv', 'Change Author', 'my_add_author_metabox', get_post_type(), 'side');

// make new author metabox that contains users that can manage this cpt
function my_add_author_metabox()
{
  $post_type_name = isset($_GET['post_type']) ? $_GET['post_type'] : get_post_type($_GET['post']);
  $roles = get_editable_roles();
  // i unset these as they are never used
  unset(
    $roles['administrator'],
    $roles['contributor'],
    $roles['author'],
    $roles['editor'],
    $roles['subscriber']
  );

  // get role that manages this cpt
  $cpt_name = '';
  $cap = 'edit_' . $post_type_name;
  foreach($roles as $role_name => $args){
    if(array_key_exists($cap, $args['capabilities'])){
      $cpt_name = $role_name;
      break;
    }
  }

  // get users that can manage this cpt
  global $post;
  $users = get_users('role=' . $cpt_name);
  $author_id = $post->post_author;
  $select = '
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="post_author_override">Change Author</label>
<select name="post_author_override" id="post_author_override" class="">
';
  foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->ID == $author_id)
      $select .= "<option value=\"{$user->ID}\" selected=\"selected\">{$user->display_name}</option>";
    else
      $select .= "<option value=\"{$user->ID}\">{$user->display_name}</option>";
  }

  $select .= '</select>';
  echo $select;

}
```

now in my cpt i dont support `author` but if you do then either remove `author` from `supports` when you `register_post_type()` or use

```
remove_meta_box('authordiv');
```

hopefully it works for you, it works for me. there probably is a better, and if you ever come across it, post it back here :)